# Как добавить LinearLayout в RelativeLayout при этом добавить его под последним элементов в RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

У меня есть RelativeLayout, в котором есть header, написанный в LinearLayout. Во время того как пользователь загружает файл с устройства, мне нужно создавать кнопку для каждого файла. Для этого я программно пытаюсь добавить еще один LinearLayout, но не могу понять как использовать свойство layout_below программно.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".files"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/week"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.95"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/tenor_sans"
            android:text="@string/files"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#6614DE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/addplus"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_items_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_items_color"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Мои попытки:

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    public void pushFile() {
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 8, 0, 0);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.purple_200);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
```

Comment: Сделайте дополнительный LinearLayout и добавляйте в него

Comment: Черт, почему я и сам об этом не подумал, спасибо, сейчас попробую!